# Python 2.7, Having problems with having iteration

Tags: python-2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random as rand

def ex_game():
    print('Instructions:','\n','Your job is to try to figure out a number of problems by your choosing and get the progress bar all GREEN, YELLOW means its there, but wrong spot, RED means its not there and there are no more of that left. After a light turns GREEN you do not have to get it right again. Trust me its easy.(Press enter to get started)')
    raw_input()
    ex_secret(int(raw_input('Number of items you would like to TRY to solve(WARNING: GAME GETS HARDER THE LARGER THE NUMBER YOU CHOOSE):')),int(raw_input('At what level would you like to play at.(1-5)')))
def ex_guess(l_sec,tries,cheat,number_items,level):
    #This is the guess choice I separated it so that I could rerun it as pleased, to put a special code in, and show the progression table
    guess_ex = []
    option_2 = ''
    option_3 = ''
    option_4 = ''
    option_5 = ''
    if level == 2 or level == 3 or level == 4 or level == 5:
         option_2 = ', white'
    if level == 3 or level == 4 or level == 5:
         option_3 = ', orange'
    if level == 4 or level == 5:
         option_4 = ', purple'
    if level == 5:
         option_5 = ', brown'
    for loop in range(number_items):
         append_guess = 'What do you beleive the solution is?(One at a time | choices: yellow, blue, black, green, red' + option_2 + option_3 + option_4 + option_5 +'):'
         guess_ex.append(raw_input(append_guess).lower())
    return guess_ex
def ex_secret(number_items,level):
    #Makes the random list of colors to solve
    secret_ex = []
    option_2 = ''
    option_3 = ''
    option_4 = ''
    option_5 = ''
    if level == 2 or level == 3 or level == 4 or level == 5:
        option_2 = ', white'
    if level == 3 or level == 4 or level == 5:
        option_3 = ', orange'
    if level == 4 or level == 5:
        option_4 = ', purple'
    if level == 5:
        option_5 = ', brown'
    for loop in range(number_items):
        secret_ex.append(rand.choice(['yellow','blue','black','green','red', option_2 , option_3, option_4, option_5]))
    for empty_check in secret_ex:
        if empty_check == '':
            ex_secret(number_items,level)
    report(secret_ex,[],0,False,number_items,level,False,False)
def report(secret,progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level,correct,end):
    #The "game"
    safe_secret = []
    for record in secret:
        safe_secret.append(record)
    if correct == True:
        print('YOU WON!')
        end = True
    if tries > 0 and cheat == False or tries > 4 and cheat:
        print(progress)
        progress = []
    if not end:
        while not correct:
            if tries == 5 and not correct:
                print('YOU LOST?!?!')
                end = True
                return end
            guess = ex_guess(len(secret),tries,cheat,number_items,level)
            super_secret = 'up up down down left right left right b a start'
            if 'give' in guess:
                tries = 4
            if super_secret in guess and not cheat:
                print('The deal has been made. Now make your "new" choices.')
                cheat = True
                tries += 6
                guess = ex_guess(len(secret),progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level)
            elif super_secret in guess and cheat:
                print('I said the deal was made now go make your new choices and leave me alone you prick.')
                guess = ex_guess(len(secret),progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level)
            elif 'stop_cheat' in guess and cheat:
                if tries > 8:
                    return 'YOU LOST, thank you for admitting to cheating though.'
                else:
                    cheat = False
                    tries -= 6
            list_counter_in = 0
            list_counter_out = 0
            list_counter_incor = 0
            while list_counter_in <= number_items - 1:
                if guess[list_counter_in] == secret[list_counter_in] and '_g' not in guess[list_counter_in]:
                    secret[list_counter_in] += ('_g')
                    guess[list_counter_in] += ('_g')
                list_counter_in += 1
            while list_counter_out <= number_items - 1:
                if guess[list_counter_out] in secret and '_g' not in guess[list_counter_out]:
                    secret_yellow_check = secret[secret.index(guess[list_counter_out])]
                    if '_y' not in secret_yellow_check:
                        secret[secret.index(guess[list_counter_out])] += '_y'
                        guess[list_counter_out] += '_y'
                list_counter_out += 1
            while list_counter_incor <= number_items - 1:
                if '_g' not in guess[list_counter_incor] and '_y' not in guess[list_counter_incor]:
                    guess[list_counter_incor] += '_r'
                list_counter_incor += 1
            for check_status in guess:
                if '_g' in check_status:
                    progress.append('GREEN')
                if '_y' in check_status:
                    progress.append('YELLOW')
                if '_r' in check_status:
                    progress.append('RED')
            if 'RED' not in progress and 'YELLOW' not in progress:
                correct = True
            if 'RED' in progress or 'YELLOW' in progress:
                tries +=1
                print('Not quite right...Lets try again!')
            report(safe_secret,progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level,correct,end)
```

Basically I have only one large issue with this code, It keeps repeating, after the player wins or loses it repeats could someone help me with this, and yes I have tried using returns instead. I am basically trying to have if they get all the correct colors in a random secret they win if they can't figure it out in 5 moves they lose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are actually a couple problems here and they mainly boil down to the fact that you are calling functions inside themselves which is generally a REALLY bad idea. I rewrote your functions so that they do not need to call themselves. Here is what I came up with. :) As a bonus I added the option to type 'quit' at any time while playing(but not while configuring and actually typing a 'quit' while configuring will crash the game) to quit the game.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random as rand

def ex_game():
    print('Instructions:','\n','Your job is to try to figure out a number of problems by your choosing and get the progress bar all GREEN, YELLOW means its there, but wrong spot, RED means its not there and there are no more of that left. After a light turns GREEN you do not have to get it right again. Trust me its easy.(Press enter to get started)')
    raw_input()
    ex_secret(int(raw_input('Number of items you would like to TRY to solve(WARNING: GAME GETS HARDER THE LARGER THE NUMBER YOU CHOOSE):')),int(raw_input('At what level would you like to play at.(1-5)')))
def ex_guess(l_sec,tries,cheat,number_items,level):
    #This is the guess choice I separated it so that I could rerun it as pleased, to put a special code in, and show the progression table
    guess_ex = []
    colors = ['yellow', 'blue', 'black', 'green', 'red']

    if level >= 2:
        colors.append('white')
    if level >= 3:
        colors.append('orange')
    if level >= 4:
        colors.append('purple')
    if level >= 5:
        colors.append('brown')

    for loop in range(number_items):
         append_guess = 'What do you beleive the solution is?(One at a time | choices: ' + str(colors) + '):'
         input = raw_input(append_guess).lower()

         if input == 'quit':
            return 'quit'
         guess_ex.append(input)

    return guess_ex
def ex_secret(number_items,level):
    secret_ex = []
    optionalColors = []
    if level >= 2:
        optionalColors.append('white')
    if level >= 3:
        optionalColors.append('orange')
    if level >= 4:
        optionalColors.append('purple')
    if level >= 5:
        optionalColors.append('brown')

    for loop in range(number_items):
        secret_ex.append(rand.choice(['yellow','blue','black','green','red']+optionalColors))

    report(secret_ex,[],0,False,number_items,level,False)
def report(secret,progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level,correct):
    #The "game"
    safe_secret = []
    for record in secret:
        safe_secret.append(record)
    if correct == True:
        print('YOU WON!')
        end = True
    if tries > 0 and cheat == False or tries > 4 and cheat:
        print(progress)
        progress = []
    while not correct:
        if tries == 5 and not correct:
            print('YOU LOST?!?!')
            raw_input('Thanks for Playing!')
            return
        guess = ex_guess(len(secret),tries,cheat,number_items,level)
        super_secret = 'up up down down left right left right b a start'
        if 'give' in guess:
            tries = 4
        if super_secret in guess and not cheat:
            print('The deal has been made. Now make your "new" choices.')
            cheat = True
            tries += 6
            guess = ex_guess(len(secret),progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level)
        elif super_secret in guess and cheat:
            print('I said the deal was made now go make your new choices and leave me alone you prick.')
            guess = ex_guess(len(secret),progress,tries,cheat,number_items,level)
        elif 'stop_cheat' in guess and cheat:
            if tries > 8:
                return 'YOU LOST, thank you for admitting to cheating though.'
            else:
                cheat = False
                tries -= 6
        if guess == 'quit':
            raw_input('Thanks for Playing!')
            return
        list_counter_in = 0
        list_counter_out = 0
        list_counter_incor = 0
        while list_counter_in <= number_items - 1:
            if guess[list_counter_in] == secret[list_counter_in] and '_g' not in guess[list_counter_in]:
                secret[list_counter_in] += ('_g')
                guess[list_counter_in] += ('_g')
            list_counter_in += 1
        while list_counter_out <= number_items - 1:
            if guess[list_counter_out] in secret and '_g' not in guess[list_counter_out]:
                secret_yellow_check = secret[secret.index(guess[list_counter_out])]
                if '_y' not in secret_yellow_check:
                    secret[secret.index(guess[list_counter_out])] += '_y'
                    guess[list_counter_out] += '_y'
            list_counter_out += 1
        while list_counter_incor <= number_items - 1:
            if '_g' not in guess[list_counter_incor] and '_y' not in guess[list_counter_incor]:
                guess[list_counter_incor] += '_r'
            list_counter_incor += 1
        for check_status in guess:
            if '_g' in check_status:
                progress.append('GREEN')
            if '_y' in check_status:
                progress.append('YELLOW')
            if '_r' in check_status:
                progress.append('RED')
        if 'RED' not in progress and 'YELLOW' not in progress:
            correct = True
        if 'RED' in progress or 'YELLOW' in progress:
            tries +=1
            print('Not quite right...Lets try again!')
ex_game()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing these out to me I will try not to call functions inside themselves again.

Comment: I wouldn't say NEVER do it...it is called recursion and it is a useful tool...but it's kind of buggy in python sometimes.